# Grails Render Partial Template to Div

Tags: ajax, grails

I have a form page where the user selects a filter and a table on the bottom of the page updates.  Each line in the table has a hyperlink in column one that associates a line item to an item in the database.  I am not using GORM.

I need to be able to send the current filters to the controller via AJAX (functioning).  Then I need to render a partial template (to a div) that loads the data created by a query based on the client's request parameters.

GSP:

```
....
<button onClick="generate_table()" class="pure-button">Generate Table</button>
...
<div id="selection_table">This should load with data</div>
...
```

JS:

```
//Link for AJAX
    var url =  "${g.createLink(action:'generate_table', controller: "statusReports")}";
    //The actual call
    $.getJSON(url, {
        period: JSON.stringify($("#period").val()),
        ...
        ...
    }, function(data) {
        $('#selection_table').empty();
    }).done(function(data) {
        //I need to load the template at this point?
    })
```

Controller:

```
def generate_table(){
    def table_data = statusReportsService.generate_titles(params)
    // Table data is already a map
    // What do I need to render here?  The template is named _selectionTable.gsp and should use table_data to generate html.
}
```

Partial:

I still haven't written the code for this yet.  For now it is just some random text to see if I can even load the template when I press the button

Comment: In your controller: `render(template: 'selectionTable', model: table_data)` and then in your jquery: `$('#selection_table').html(data)` ... That should do the trick ;)

Comment: I'm receiving the template, but it's not being loaded into the div.  Should the jquery you mentioned be here ...}).done(function(data){---here---})?

Should I use something other than $.getJSON() because I'm not trying to get JSON, but rather render a template?

Comment: Doh, yeah, you should use `$.get` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
render(template: 'selectionTable', model: table_data)
```

In your GSP/HTML you need to use `$.get` and use the following:

```
$('#selection_table').html(data)
```

That should do the trick!